# Dropdown is not showing options passed as props

Tags: reactjs

I have created separate functional component which can be used more than once throughout a React project. Therefore, I tried to extract it as a new function component and pass the necessary props to it. I dont know why but the options on select dropdown are not showing... Thank you for any help.

// General Component //

```
   import React, { useState } from 'react';
   import Dropdown from '../Dropdown';

   function CategoryOfWork() {
     const [value, setValue] = useState('fruit');

     const options = [
       { label: 'Fruit', value: 'fruit' },
       { label: 'Vegetable', value: 'vegetable' },
       { label: 'Meat', value: 'meat' },
     ];

     const handleChange = (event: any) => {
       setValue(event.target.value);
     };

     return <Dropdown options={options} value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
   }

   export default Dropdown;
```

// Component where I want to see options//

```
   const Dropdown = ({ value, options, onChange }: ICategoryOfWork) => {
     <select
       value={value}
       onChange={onChange}
     >
       {options?.map((option) => (
          <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
       ))}
     </select>
   }
```

// typescript//

```
   interface ICategoryOfWork {
     value: string;
     options: {
      label: string;
       value: string;
     }[];
     onChange: (event: any) => void;
   }

   export default ICategoryOfWork;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to return something from your `Dropdown` component, so you need to add `return` keyword before rendered element. Secondly you should always add `key` when you render any list in react, so add `key={option}` value to the option tag. Working code: https://playcode.io/956031

Comment: Hi @kriss thank you for your answer. I have added a key and it is in return. I'm still facing an issue ;/

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
const Dropdown = ({ value, options, onChange }: ICategoryOfWork) => {
  return (
    <select value={value} onChange={onChange}>
      {options?.map((option) => (
        <option value={option.value} key={option.value}>
          {option.label}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};
```

You can remove the return too:

```
const Dropdown = ({ value, options, onChange }: ICategoryOfWork) => (
  <select value={value} onChange={onChange}>
    {options?.map((option) => (
      <option value={option.value} key={option.value}>
        {option.label}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
);
```

Here is an example:

[image: Edit reverent-zeh-ed1f19]